# How can I make a scrollable TabBar...?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I'm working on an app that needs many TabBar Items (6 or 7). I don't think users like to click the "More" button on TabBars, so I'm wondering how to make my own TabBar that slides from left to right, so one can easily access all the buttons on the tabbar without pressing "More."

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the other answer that it's a bad idea from a design standpoint.

Nevertheless, the technical answer is that you can simply embed a `UITabBar` in a `UIScrollView`.  If you set the tab bar's width and the scroll view's `contentSize` appropriately, the tab bar will be scrollable.  You will probably want to turn off bouncing and scroll indicators.

I didn't try it with a `UITarBarController`.

Comment: Is it possible to make the tab bar's scrolling behaviour to be circular ? Like the first element should come at the last while scrolling and so on ?

Answer (score 4):

Opinions on whether this is a good idea or not aside

A simple carousel should be fairly simple to implement from scratch using a UIScrollView with UIButton subviews. which will provide all the scroll mechanics for you

As a sample idea.

- A UISCrollView which spans the width of the device.
- N buttons across the scroll content pane
- Restrict scroller to horizontal scrolling.
- Provide selected and unselected images for the buttons
- Create glue code to ensure only one button is selected at a time (like Radio buttons)

But I do agree with the other posters that its a bad UI idea. Id be thinking UIToolbar for this.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from considerations about UX and UI guidelines, a way you can implement such thing is implementing a tab bar from scratch. You can even find a [tutorial here](http://www.hollance.com/2011/11/mhtabbarcontroller-a-custom-tab-bar-for-ios-5-using-the-new-container-apis/) for iOS5.

Actually, implementing a tab bar and a tab bar controller is not difficult as it may appear at first sight, but given the effort involved, you could also ask you what value this kind of design add to your app and to the user experience.

In any case, if you decide to go for this path (a scrollable tab bar), I would suggest to make it such that the user cannot be misguided into thinking it's a standard tab bar.

Comment: You don't have to implement it from scratch.  I tested putting a `UITabBar` in a `UIScrollView` and it worked fine.

Comment: @rob mayoff: thanks, I did not know it... on the other hand, say you want to differentiate the scrollable tab bar from the "normal" one, then in this case re-implementing it might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

That's against about every design guideline ever written for iOS.

(I know that Gift Plan for iOS has a scrollable tab bar, but it never hides items from the user.)

Comment: i agree. you seriously should consider a different app design or even 2 or 3 different apps, if you serioulsy need 7 tabs

Comment: I agree with you. I will review the design. And use an "more" Button  if needed. thanks all

Comment: Guys, I really can't find any point on the iOS Guidelines that says that a Scrollable TabBar would be unrecommended. Could you guys please elaborate on this? Facebook, for example, uses exactly this feature on a company/artist/search page. The iOS Guidelines here: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/

Comment: First, this question is more than 5 years old now. Second, Apple doesn't advise against green text with pink drop shadows, but that doesn't make it okay to use. You won't find a scrollable tab bar anywhere in iOS, so users won't expect yours to be. Unexpected behavior in iOS apps == bad, pretty much.

Answer (score 2):

The HOW to do it has been accepted,

MOBILE DESIGN PATTERNS are not cast in concrete - it is about what is appropriate for YOUR app.
It used to be that web pages scrolled vertically and side-scrolling was frowned on.

But the tablet has been a game changer - people EXPECT to swipe side to side.

A comment on one case when scrolling tab view is actually highly appropriate ..

(a) Look at xFeed in App Store
This has 10+ topics like News Sports ... , easy to scroll to topic and click takes you to RSS feeds under it.
This is truly convenient for user, and in my opinion appropriate.
The alternative is to go back and forth between a menu of some kind and the target view - which could be a 2nd option, but from a quick browse experience this is good.

(b) USA Today is another example - even on its main website, has the < > arrows to scroll between topics or you can click on tabs at top. Admittedly the tabs themselves don't scroll, but you get the idea. The entire site, and the mobile experience for USA Today is strongly optimized around side swipeing between chapters.

(c) Presentations and content sites have come to be side scrolling as well.

(d) FINALLY on a Human Happiness viewpoint! People WANT TO TOUCH and PLAY with their mobile stuff. Not just tap! 
So mobile touch is quite happy here. One more thing to swipe and slide :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link of project with custom scrollable tab bar:

[github - scrollable tab bar by BananaDev](https://github.com/valitovaza/scrollableTabbar)

It's free and provides a wide variety of customization options allowing you to fully change control.